# Checking all points in a list are inside a rectangle

Tags: python-3.x

I've written the below code but for some reason it only works with the first point inside my list:

```
def allIn(firstCorner=(0,0), secondCorner=(0,0), pointList=[]):
    x1, y1 = firstCorner[0], firstCorner[1]
    x2, y2 = secondCorner[0], secondCorner[1]

    for i in range(len(pointList)):
        xa = pointList[i][0]
        ya = pointList[i][1]

        if (xa in range(x1,x2+1)) and (ya in range(y1,y2+1)):
            return True
        elif (xa in range(x2,x1+1)) and (ya in range(y2,y1+1)):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

This code only works to check the first coordinates inside my list:

```
allIn((0,0), (5,5), [(1,1), (0,0), (5,5)])
```

returns True

however

```
allIn((0,0), (5,5), [(1,1), (8,0), (5,6)])
```

also returns True

Any suggestions?

Comment: You return `True` if the first element in your list checks out. Which it does in your test-case.

Comment: In both In and Not-In tests you immediately end the function with `return` after the first test. `return` is not a state or variable of some kind, it **stops** whatever the function is doing and returns to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function to:

```
def all_in(first_corner=(0,0), second_corner=(0,0), point_list=None):
   point_list = point_list or []
   x1, y1 = first_corner[0], first_corner[1]
   x2, y2 = second_corner[0], second_corner[1]
   return all(p[0] in range(x1,x2+1) and p[1] in range(y1,y2+1) for p in point_list)
```

This avoid checking for any point, and return `False` as soon as a point is not inside the rectangle.

Comment: Could improve run time by extracting range calls to variables